# sum the elements of different files in python

Tags: python

I have multiples files with similar names (only change the suffix). I want to sum the values of the files in a new file. For example: file `energy.dat.1` contains values in matrix format, and file `energy.dat.2` has the same format but another values.

For example:

`energy.dat.1` file constains `([[1, 2], [3, 4]])`

`energy.dat.2` file constains `([[0, 1], [1, 3]])`

I want to obtain another one, `total_energy`, which contains the result of the sum (i.e.: `([[1, 3], [4, 7]])`).

---

Because I have a lot of files I have done:

```
for file_name in os.listdir('.'):
    if file_name[0:10] == "energy.dat":
        total_energy = total_energy +
                  np.sum(
                     np.loadtxt(file_name)
                  )
```

(Previously I defined the array `total_energy` with the correct dimensions.)

Problem: the result, `total_energy`, is a matrix with values equals to the sum of all elements of the files (`([[13, 13], [13, 13]])`) instead of (`([[1, 3], [4, 7]])`)

Do you have any ideas to reach the result I want?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not a numpy expert, but can't you just omit the np.sum part ?

Comment: You are right!. It was easier I thought. Thanks I lot.

Comment: Perhaps the if block could be refactored as `total_energy += np.sum(np.loadtxt(file_name))` - it seems redundant making twice the sum, tough; if `np.sum()` is expendable, then just `total_energy += np.loadtext(filename)` might do the work? PD: built-in Python point of view, never used `np` library (I didn't even know it existed)

Comment: Also, instead of doing `os.listdir` and then checking for the prefix to match `energy.dat`, it might be easier to just use `glob.glob`, e.g. `for file_name in glob.glob('energy.dat*'):`